# MarkLogic Join Query

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Hi I am new to marklogic and in Xquery world. I am not able to think of starting point to write the following logic in Marklogic Xquery. I would be thankful if somebody can give me idea/sample so I can achieve the following:

I want to Query A.XML based on a word lookup in B.XML. Query should produce C.XML. The logic should be as follows:

A.XML

```
<root>
<content> The state passed its first ban on using a handheld cellphone while driving in 2004 Nokia Vodafone Nokia Growth Recession Creicket HBO</content>
</root>
```

B.XML

```
<WordLookUp>
<companies>
    <company name="Vodafone">Vodafone</company>
    <company name="Nokia">Nokia</company>
</companies>
<topics>
    <topic group="Sports">Cricket</topic>
    <topic group="Entertainment">HBO</topic>
    <topic group="Finance">GDP</topic>
</topics>
<moods>
    <mood number="4">Growth</mood>
    <mood number="-5">Depression</mood>
    <mood number="-3">Recession</mood>
</moods>
```

C.XML (Result XML)

```
<root>
    <content> The state passed its first ban on using a handheld cellphone while driving in 2004 Nokia Vodafone Nokia Growth Recession Creicket HBO</content>
    <updatedElement>
        <companies>
            <company count="1">Vodafone</company>
            <company count="2">Nokia</company>
        </companies>
        <mood>1</mood>
        <topics>
             <topic count="1">Sports</topic>
             <topic count="1">Entertainment</topic>
        </topics>
            <word-count>22</word-count>
    </updatedElement>
    </root>
```

1. Search each company/text() of A.xml in B.xml, if match found create tag:
   TAG {company count="Number of occurrence of that word"}company/@name
   {/company}
2. Search each topic/text() of A.xml in B.xml, if match found create tag 
   TAG {topic topic="Number of occurrences of that word"}topic/@group{/topic}
3. Search each mood/text() of A.xml in B.xml, if match found 
   [occurrences of first word * {/mood[first word]/@number}] + [occurrences of second word * {/mood[second word]/@number})]....
4. get the word count of  element.

Comment: You are counting "2004" as a word. Could you, please, edit the question and define "word" exactly? Would thw words in `<content>` be always space-separated or could there be other delimiters? Is "word-count" one word or two? What about FY-2012?

Comment: It might be interesting to know that a fully-compliant XQuery solution exists that doesn't use any extension functions, and thus can be run under any compliant XQuery implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is simpler/shorter and fully compliant XQuery not containing any implementation extensions, which make it work with any compliant XQuery 1.0 processor:**

```
let $content := doc('file:///c:/temp/delete/A.xml')/*/*,
      $lookup := doc('file:///c:/temp/delete/B.xml')/*,
      $words := tokenize($content, '\W+')[.]
         return
           <root>
            {$content}
             <updatedElement>
               <companies>
                  {for $c in $lookup/companies/*,
                       $occurs in count(index-of($words, $c))
                     return
                       if($occurs)
                          then
                            <company count="{$occurs}">
                              {$c/text()}
                            </company>
                          else ()
                  }
               </companies>
               <mood>
                  {
                   sum($lookup/moods/*[false or index-of($words, data(.))]/@number)
                  }
               </mood>
               <topics>
                 {for $t in $lookup/topics/*,
                      $occurs in count(index-of($words, $t))
                    return
                      if($occurs)
                         then
                           <topic count="{$occurs}">
                             {data($t/@group)}
                           </topic>
                         else ()
                  }
               </topics>
               <word-count>{count($words)}</word-count>
              </updatedElement>
          </root>
```

**When applied on the provided files A.xml and B.XML (contained in the local directory `c:/temp/delete`), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <content> The state passed its first ban on using a handheld cellphone while driving in 2004 Nokia Vodafone Nokia Growth Recession Cricket HBO</content>
   <updatedElement>
      <companies>
         <company count="1">Vodafone</company>
         <company count="2">Nokia</company>
      </companies>
      <mood>1</mood>
      <topics>
         <topic count="1">Sports</topic>
         <topic count="1">Entertainment</topic>
      </topics>
      <word-count>22</word-count>
   </updatedElement>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

This was a fun one, and I learned a few things in the process. Thanks!

Note: to get the results you wanted, I fixed a typo in A.xml ("Creicket" -> "Cricket").

The following solution uses two MarkLogic-specific functions:

- `cts:highlight` (for replacing matching text with nodes which you can then count)
- `cts:tokenize` (for breaking up a given string into word, space, and punctuation parts)

It also includes some powerful magic specific to those two functions, respectively:

- the dynamic binding of the special variable `$cts:text` (which isn't really necessary for this particular use case, but I digress), and
- the data model extension which adds these subtypes of `xs:string`:

  - `cts:word`,
  - `cts:space`, and
  - `cts:punctuation`.

Enjoy!

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

(: Generic function using MarkLogic's ability to find query matches within a single node :)
declare function local:find-matches($content, $search-text) {
  cts:highlight($content, $search-text, <MATCH>{$cts:text}</MATCH>)
  //MATCH
};

(: Generic function using MarkLogic's ability to tokenize text into words, punctuation, and spaces :)
declare function local:get-words($text) {
  cts:tokenize($text)[. instance of cts:word]
};

(: The rest of this is pure XQuery :)
let $content := doc("A.xml")/root/content,
    $lookup  := doc("B.xml")/WordLookUp
return
  <root>
    {$content}
    <updatedElement>

      <companies>{
        for $company in $lookup/companies/company
        let $results := local:find-matches($content, string($company))
        where exists($results)
        return
          <company count="{count($results)}">{string($company/@name)}</company>
      }</companies>

      <mood>{
        sum(
          for $mood in $lookup/moods/mood
          let $results := local:find-matches($content, string($mood))
          return count($results) * $mood/@number
        )
      }</mood>

      <topics>{
        for $topic in $lookup/topics/topic
        let $results := local:find-matches($content, string($topic))
        where exists($results)
        return
          <topic count="{count($results)}">{string($topic/@group)}</topic>
      }</topics>

      <word-count>{
        count(local:get-words($content))
      }</word-count>

    </updatedElement>
  </root>
```

Let me know if you have any follow-up questions about how all the above works. At first, I was inclined to use `cts:search` or `cts:contains`, which are the bread and butter for search in MarkLogic. But I realized that this example wasn't so much about search (finding documents) as it was about looking up matching text within an already-given document. If you needed to extend this somehow to aggregate across a large number of documents, then you'd want to look into the additional use of `cts:search` or `cts:contains`.

One final caveat: if you think your content might have `<MATCH>` elements already, you'll want to use a different element name when calling `cts:highlight` (a name which you can guarantee won't conflict with your content's existing element names). Otherwise, you'll potentially get the wrong number of results (higher than the accurate count).

**ADDENDUM:**

I was curious if this could be done without `cts:highlight`, given that `cts:tokenize` already breaks up the text into all the words for you. The same result is produced using this alternative implementation of `local:find-matches` (provided you swap the order of the function declarations because one depends on the other):

```
(: Find word matches by comparing them one-by-one :)
declare function local:find-matches($content, $search-text) {
  local:get-words($content)[cts:stem(.) = cts:stem($search-text)]
};
```

It uses `cts:stem` to normalize the given word to its stem, so, for example searching for "pass" will match "passed", etc. However, this still won't work for multi-word (phrase) searches. So to be safe, I'd stick with using `cts:highlight`, which, like `cts:search` and `cts:contains`, can handle any cts:query you give it (including simple word/phrase searches like we do above).

Comment: Here I found that when try to find words like "Walmart Inc" or "International Walmart" both are normalize to "Walmart" (<company name="Walmart>Walmart Inc</company>", the script produce new company tag for both the cases. it should be incremented count in same company tag <company count="2">Walmart</company>. I am trying something let $companyNumber := local:find-matches($company, string($company/@name)) in company's for block not getting the correct result. Please help. THanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Might make sense to step back and ask  if you might be better served modeling your data  and or documents  for use with a document oriented database instead of an rdbms

Comment: Good point. Perhaps the above solution could be used as the document enrichment script, so that the (denormalized) C.xml would then become the basis of live application code, in which you could efficiently look up documents based on, for example, their word count (using a range index on <word-count>), etc. And maybe it would be re-run using CPF every time the <content> part is updated.

Comment: @EvanLenz: As you mentioned CPF here, I got a question, I am going to transform A.xml into C.xml at the time of ingestion using CPF framework. But the case is lookup XML (B.XML), can be changed frequently, now if it got changed, how can I updated previously transformed documents in DB. I believe CPF pipeline will work for newly inserted documents only.

Comment: I haven't personally used CPF yet, but I believe it's quite flexible. You should be able to automatically kick off an XQuery script that bulk-updates the other documents whenever B.xml is updated. Just be sure to evaluate the performance implications (how many docs need to be updated and how often B.xml gets updated). If it's too expensive (or not sufficiently scalable), then you'd want to consider an alternative approach.

Comment: Asker found this answer useful, as did Evan, even if Dimitre seemed to think it was irrelevant and down-voted it.  Perhaps Dimitre should learn more about MarkLogic before answering questions so tagged.