# Join tables in marklogic

Tags: xml, rest, xquery, marklogic, nosql

How do we join two tables and execute query?

For example,

student1.xml

```
<Students>
    <student>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <name>XYZ</name>
    </student>
</Students>
```

student2.xml

```
<Students>
    <student>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <roll>45</roll>
    </student>
</Students>
```

I need a query where I can get all the 3 values like `10,XYZ,45` from above two xml files. Is it possible in NoSql? If so How can I do that in MarkLogic?
Any approach is fine(REST, Java, Xquery...).

Thanks in advance,

Prithvi

Comment: I recommend you read a basic introduction about ML first _before_ asking questions or you could read the ML documentation. You should decide for a technology on your own (for ML XQuery would of course be the obvious choice) and read up on some concepts. A question like "is it possible in NoSql?" really does not make sense and is not particular helpful.

Comment: @dirkk Yes, I do understand but some blogs posted that we can't have joins in NoSql as it is document based database. I struck at using XQuery and cts.

Comment: You can join data together, of course. But forget about tables, tables are a relational database concept. As you can see, you have XML files and not tables. Also, forget about "NoSQL" in this context - what does this even mean? There are so many NoSQL concepts out there and ML is just one of them. Read up about XQuery and tell is more concrete what you "struck at" and ask a much more specific question.

Comment: Please share some code. We can help review mistakes, but not write code for you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [MarkLogic Join Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157616/marklogic-join-query)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a "documents as tables" approach. However MarkLogic is a document-oriented database, so it's better to treat documents as rows. Create documents like this:

```
    <!-- document URI is "student/10" -->
    <student>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <roll>45</roll>
    </student>

    <!-- document URI is "student/17" -->
    <student>
        <Id>17</Id>
        <name>fubar</name>
        <roll>45</roll>
    </student>
```

Now you can get everything you need to know about the student with `doc('student/10')` or `doc('student/17')`. That's what a document-oriented database is good at, and you should play to its strengths.

Of course there are ways to do joins anyway: see [MarkLogic Join Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157616/marklogic-join-query) and https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql for example.